# selecting multiple columns in pl/sql collection

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

Actually i have created following procedure,which is working fine.

```
CREATE or REPLACE PROCEDURE GET_NOS(
firstDate IN DATE,
secondDate IN DATE,
thirdDate IN DATE,
fourthDate IN DATE,
test IN VARCHAR2,
Slnt_Entity OUT TEST.RefCsr
)
AS
 DemoTable CRITERIA_LIST_TABLE;
 BEGIN


SELECT column1 BULK COLLECT INTO DemoTable FROM opr_test where call_date between firstDate AND secondDate AND id=test
MINUS
SELECT column1 FROM opr_test where call_date between thirdDate AND fourthDate AND id=test;


OPEN Slnt_Entity FOR SELECT * FROM TABLE(
                                            CAST (
                                                    DemoTable AS CRITERIA_LIST_TABLE
                                                 )
                                    ) Nos;

END;
/
```

2. second

```
create or replace TYPE "CRITERIA_LIST_TABLE" as table of varchar2(20);
/
```

1. Third

   ```
   create or replace PACKAGE "TEST"
   AS
   TYPE RefCsr IS REF CURSOR;
   END TEST;
    /
   ```

   Now i want to change my query like this

   ```
   SELECT column1,column2 BULK COLLECT INTO DemoTable FROM opr_test where call_date between firstDate AND secondDate AND id=test
   MINUS
   SELECT column1,column2 FROM opr_test where call_date between thirdDate AND fourthDate AND id=test;
   ```

so i changed the procedure like

```
CREATE or REPLACE PROCEDURE GET_NOS(
firstDate IN DATE,
secondDate IN DATE,
thirdDate IN DATE,
fourthDate IN DATE,
test IN VARCHAR2,
Slnt_Entity OUT TEST.RefCsr
 )
AS

CURSOR c1 IS SELECT column1,column2 FROM opr_test;
  create or replace TYPE "ABC" IS TABLE OF c1%ROWTYPE;
DemoTable ABC;

BEGIN


 SELECT column1 BULK COLLECT INTO DemoTable FROM opr_test where call_date between firstDate AND secondDate AND id=test
 MINUS
 SELECT column1 FROM opr_test where call_date between thirdDate AND fourthDate AND id=test;


  OPEN Slnt_Entity FOR SELECT * FROM TABLE(
                                            CAST (
                                                    DemoTable AS CRITERIA_LIST_TABLE
                                                 )
                                    ) Nos;

  END;
  /
```

But this is incorrect,please tell me how the procedure will look like

Comment: If you supplied error messages etc that you were getting then it'd make replying easier...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

user595014, to help you with the problem you are having and have several questions open on StackOverflow about. Read this article from ORACLE-BASE about creating and returning oracle REF_CURSOR types.

If you read it all it also gives you a demo on how to return a ref_cursor to a calling Java program (something you have asked me about in a previous question).

It will give you everything you need to sort out your issue.

http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/UsingRefCursorsToReturnRecordsets.php

Comment: Could be useful to include relevant parts of the link content in your answer. Just in case that website changes or dies.